# Button name using list comprehension

Tags: python, telegram

I have this function which I'd like to change the button name to either PENDING or VERIFIED depending on the value 1 or 0 in a cell.

I tried
`fstring = f"{'Pending' if df.Sold[payment_verified(order).index[0]] == 0 else 'Verified'}"`
which works but not inside the function:

```
def gen_verifymarkup(chatid):
    verifymarkup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    verifymarkup.row_width = 2
    my_orders = check_my_orders(chatid)
    for order in my_orders:
        try:
            fstring = ['Pending' if (df.Sold[payment_verified(order).index][0] == 0) else 'Verified']
            verifymarkup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(f"{order}", callback_data=f"cb_verify-{order}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(f"{fstring}",callback_data=f"cb_verified-{order}"))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            
        print(order)
    return verifymarkup
```

Thank you!
UPDATE:
I managed to do it...

```
for order in my_orders:
    try:
        if list(payment_verified2(order)["Sold"].values())[0] == 1:
            print(order)
            verifymarkup.add(
                InlineKeyboardButton(f"{order}", callback_data=f"cb_verify-{order}"),
                InlineKeyboardButton(f"Verified", callback_data=f"cb_verified-{order}"),
            )
        elif list(payment_verified2(order)["Sold"].values())[0] != 1:
            verifymarkup.add(
                InlineKeyboardButton(f"{order}", callback_data=f"cb_verify-{order}"),
                InlineKeyboardButton(f"Pending", callback_data=f"cb_verified-{order}"),
            )
            print("fail")
    except:
        verifymarkup.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(f"{order}", callback_data=f"cb_verify-{order}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(f"Pending", callback_data=f"cb_verified-{order}"),
        )
        continue
```

Comment: Why exactly are you creating `fstring` as a list? There isn't even any for loop in your list comprehension.

Comment: List comprehension will return a list whether the condition meets or fails. For example, it will return `fstring=['Pending']` or `fstring=['Verified']`. Did you try it without list comprehension? I mean what's the purpose of using it here?